# Check if current WooCommerce product has an image Gallery to run a jQuery script

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, product, image-gallery

For some reason, the code I'm using does not seem to load unless I inspect and run a debug. Perhaps someone else can review and make sure?

While the first check makes sure it's a product page, I would like a secondary check making sure the product has a gallery and if not - return.

This is the code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'image_swap_on_hover' );
function image_swap_on_hover() {

    if ( ! is_product() ) return;
    // if (???) // check if product has image gallery

    ?>

        <script>

            jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

                $( window ).load( function() {
        
                    $( '.flexslider' ).flexslider( {
            
                    animation: "slide",
                    controlNav: "thumbnails",
                    start: function() {
                }
            }
        );

        $( ".flex-control-thumbs li img" ).hover( function() {

            $(this).click();
        
            }
        );
            }
        );
            }
        );

    </script>

<?php
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For your loading problem**, don't use jQuery `ready` event as it comes after `load` event, so the `load` event never get triggered in your code.

You can use the `WC_Product` method `get_gallery_image_ids()` as follows:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'image_swap_on_hover' );
function image_swap_on_hover() {
    if ( ! is_product() ) 
        return;

    global $product;

    if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    // Get product gallery image ids
    $gallery_image_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
    
    // Check if product gallery image ids is not empty
    if ( ! empty($gallery_image_ids) ) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery( function($) {
        $( window ).load( function() {
            console.log( 'window LOAD event' ); // Only for testing (to be removed)

            $( '.flexslider' ).flexslider( {
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: "thumbnails",
                start: function() {
                    // do something
                }
            });
    
            $( ".flex-control-thumbs li img" ).hover( function() {
                $(this).click();
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That last edit made it all work.

Comment: actually, nothing happens after reloading the page. it was working and stopped working using this last edit.

Comment: if you don't mind, could you please review this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65540202/add-line-break-row-between-quantity-and-add-to-cart-on-woocommerce-product-pag

No matter what I do, nothing works.

Comment: @HaroldAldersen My code works on single product pages when a product has an image gallery and in the javascript browser console, the text log  "'window LOAD event'" appears so the load event works. Now I don't know if your flexslider code works as this is not what you asked.

Comment: @HaroldAldersen Sorry but for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65540202/add-line-break-row-between-quantity-and-add-to-cart-on-woocommerce-product-pag question I don't have a useful working answer.

Comment: Ok. Just to be clear so that I understand you; can it be done or not? Just so that I know if I should "give up" or keep trying.

Comment: @HaroldAldersen for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65540202/add-line-break-row-between-quantity-and-add-to-cart-on-woocommerce-product-pag I don't know, I don't have the solution for now…